# How to prevent Voiceover resetting to the first page when navigating SwiftUI TabView?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, voiceover, swiftui-tabview

I want to use Voiceover to navigate a simple TabView with .page styling, but it keeps jumping back to page 0 when I navigate using the dots (swiping up).

Is this a bug? How can I override it?

[Gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bja53.gif)

My Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var tab: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tab) {

            VStack {
                Text("Page 0")
            }
            .tag(0)

            VStack {
                Text("Page 1")
            }
            .tag(1)

            VStack {
                Text("Page 2")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I replicate this? It works fine on the simulator.

Comment: I am using a physical device - iPhone 14 Pro on iOS 17.2. How are you using voiceover on simulator?

Comment: I'm not. I was wondering if that was a possibility, so that I could help.